# How can I start a Robocup match without using the monitor's kickoff command (for shell script)

Tags: java, simulation, agent

I have two robocup teams that I want to play against each other via shell script (so that they play a 100 or so games). I am using the ATAN library and the teams will play each other, but the problem is that I cannot start a game without using the monitor's kickoff command. Is there a function in ATAN or a something I can say to the server to do the kickoff without manually doing it in the monitor?

Thanks.

-Ted

Answer (score 0):

Pretty sure you can't just automate kick off, but if it helps, Ctrl + K is a shortcut to kick off